# Reactively doing calculations in columns, based on the values of user input in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

I have an app in which the user inputs text and numeric information in a shiny DT, and then those values are saved in a dataframe. One of the columns, `Duration`, intakes a number and then two other columns, `Start` and `End`, do calculations based on those values. I know that the calculations are being done because if I change the value for `Duration` from 0 to any number, the math is done. The problem is that if I change the value for `Duration` in the app, the values for `Start` and `End` do not reactively change.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would be?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  #numeric input that determines the number of rows for the phases table
  numericInput("num_exps", 
               label = "Enter the number of experimental phases:",
               min = 1,
               max = 1000,
               value = 1),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput('phasesTable'),
  
  br(),
  br(),
  
  verbatimTextOutput("reactive_verbatim"),
  br(),
  DT::dataTableOutput('habit_table'),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("habit_verbatim"),
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Number output for number of conditions
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_exps })
  
  #Creating a data.frame that is dynamic in its length
  phases_df <- reactive({data.frame(
    'Phase Number' = sapply(1: as.integer(input$num_exps), function(i) { i })  )
  })
  
  #calculating the start and end times for each phase, and adding them to phases_df as timings
  timings <- reactive({
    req(phases_df()) %>% 
      mutate('Phase Name' = "") %>%
      mutate('Phase Group' = 0) %>%
      mutate(Duration = 0) %>%
      mutate(End = cumsum(Duration)) %>%
      mutate(Start = End - Duration) %>%
      relocate(Start, .before = End)
  })
  
  #Convert dat1 reactive to data frame and set to a reactiveVal
  Dat = reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    d = timings()
    d = as.data.frame(d)
    Dat(d)
  })
  
  #columns to not be editable
  checkboxesColumns_list <- c(0, 1, 5:9)
  
  output$phasesTable <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      timings(), 
      #escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns_list)),
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
                     ordering = FALSE,
                     scrollx = FALSE,
                     searching = FALSE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     info = FALSE),
      selection = "none")}, server = FALSE)
  
  #edit the shiny datatable and dataframe based on the edits
  observeEvent(input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]], { 
    info <- input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]] 
    
    Dat(editData(Dat(), info))
  })
  
  #print the verbatim of the dataframe
  output$reactive_verbatim <- renderPrint({ 
    str(Dat())
  })
  
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a stab at this. I'm sure there's a cleaner solution but I think this will get you in the right direction. Instead of using the `timings` reactive for generating your datatable. I decided to use `Dat` since it's easier to work with a reactiveVal here instead of a reactive.

I created two helper functions `create_timings` and `create_dt`.

`create_timings` builds out the initial df from the `phases_df()` to set up `timings()`. Then after that everything is using the Dat reactiveVal. When new changes are made, `create_timings` is run with the updated data. This updates `Dat` which invalidates `output$phasesTable` triggering it to output the new DT.

[image]

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  #Number output for number of conditions
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$num_exps })
  
  #Creating a data.frame that is dynamic in its length
  phases_df <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      'Phase Number' = sapply(1:as.integer(input$num_exps), function(i) {i})
    )
  })
  
  # Initialize timings_df then perform calculations based on user input for "Duration"
  create_timings = function(phases) {
    # init df
    if(length(phases) == 1) {
      phases %>%
        mutate(
          'Phase Name' = "",
          'Phase Group' = 0,
           Duration = 0,
           Start = 0,
           End = 0
        )
    } else {
      phases %>%
        mutate(End = cumsum(Duration)) %>%
        mutate(Start = End - Duration)
    }
  }
  
  # Helper dt func
  create_dt = function(dt, checkboxesColumns_list = c(0, 1, 5:9)) {
    datatable(
      dt, 
      #escape = FALSE,
      editable = list(target = "cell", disable = list(columns = checkboxesColumns_list)),
      options = list(paging = FALSE,
                     ordering = FALSE,
                     scrollx = FALSE,
                     searching = FALSE,
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     info = FALSE),
      selection = "none")
  }
  
  #calculating the start and end times for each phase, and adding them to phases_df as timings
  timings <- reactive({
    req(phases_df())
    create_timings(phases_df())
  })
  
  #Convert dat1 reactive to data frame and set to a reactiveVal
  Dat = reactiveVal()
  
  observe({
    d = timings()
    d = as.data.frame(d)
    Dat(d)
  })
  
  #columns to not be editable
  # checkboxesColumns_list <- c(0, 1, 5:9)
  
  # Uses the reactive Dat() object here
  output$phasesTable <- renderDT({
    create_dt(dt = Dat())
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  #edit the shiny datatable and dataframe based on the edits
  observeEvent(input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]], { 
    info <- input[["phasesTable_cell_edit"]]
    
    # This updates Dat with new data which is first passed into `create_timings`
    Dat(create_timings(editData(Dat(), info)))
  })
  
  #print the verbatim of the dataframe
  output$reactive_verbatim <- renderPrint({ 
    str(Dat())
  })
  
}
```